# Attempting to compile/run Java code on Ubuntu, Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument

Tags: java, ubuntu, pdfbox

I am attempting to run the following Java code on an Ubuntu system.  The code should create a blank PDF file using the pdfbox class:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BlankPDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PDDocument doc = null;
        try{
            doc = new PDDocument();
        } catch (IOException ie){
            System.out.println(ie);
        }
        doc.addPage(new PDPage());
        try{
            doc.save("Empty PDF.pdf");
            doc.close();
        } catch (Exception io){
            System.out.println(io);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following class dependencies in the same directory as the script:

- pdfbox-1.7.0.jar
- jempbox-1.7.0.jar
- fontbox-1.7.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

I used the following command to compile the script:

```
sudo javac BlankPDF.java -classpath pdfbox-1.7.0.jar:fontbox-1.7.0.jar:jempbox-1.7.0.jar:commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

Which returned no output and created a .class file (indicating that the compilation worked correctly?)

But when I attempt to run the code using the following command:

```
sudo java BlankPDF -classpath pdfbox-1.7.0.jar:fontbox-1.7.0.jar:jempbox-1.7.0.jar:commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
    at BlankPDF.main(BlankPDF.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 1 more
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the class must be the last argument to `java`. The flags must precede it. If you put flags at the end of the command lines, as here, they are ignored. So:

```
java -classpath .:pdfbox-1.7.0.jar:fontbox-1.7.0.jar:jempbox-1.7.0.jar:commons-logging-1.1.1.jar BlankPDF
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! When looking online for examples the -classpath was always at the start, but I subconsciously moved it to the end like I am use to with traditional flags

Answer (score 2):

With ref to above answer,don't forget to add current directory (with dot sign) as well in command with jars in classpath

```
java -classpath hello.jar:. SampleProgram
```

Comment: +1 Good catch, I didn't notice that -- that would be the *second* problem he'd have!